# current_timestamp only get year, month, and day

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an sql query that gets the current timestamp but it gets the entire timestamp and renders it via php. I was wondering how I could only get the year, month, and day and in this format : (month/day/year)

query :

```
SELECT badge_id, merchant_id, quest_title, quest_price, quest_date, quest_points 
FROM quests WHERE quest_id = $id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('(%m/%d/%Y)', now()) AS datestring
```

Comment: Yes. You hadn't edited your question at the time I wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) and [date()](http://php.net/date)

```
<?php
echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime("2011-10-25 00:11:22"));
```